# Identical Custom Cells being output (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary, custom-cell

I am trying to create a custom `TableView` that will output custom cells depending on the keys contained in a `Dictionary`. I have created classes and outlets for each custom cell, but when I build and run; the same custom cell is displayed multiple times. I have the correct number of cells being displayed (i.e. the same as number of keys present in the dictionary) but I can't seem to differentiate between outputted cells.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataDict.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (dataDict.indexForKey("Number") != nil) {
        let firstcell:MyFirstCell = self.scanConfirmTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("scanfirst", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyFirstCell
        return firstcell
    }

    else if (dataDict.indexForKey("Social") != nil) {
        let secondcell:MySecondCell = self.scanConfirmTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("scansecond", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MySecondCell
        return secondcell
    }
else {
        let emptycell:ScanEmptyCell = self.scanConfirmTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("scanemptycell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ScanEmptyCell
        return emptycell
    }
```

I have searched previous posts on here and found an option to use something like:

```
let currentTag = dataDict[indexPath.row]
```

But I am getting an error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String:String]' with an index type 'Int'.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: `dataDict` is a dictionary or an array? also show the `dataDict` content.

Comment: dataDict is a dictionary - I have added a breakpoint and printed the value which outputs: ["Number": "test", "Social": "test1", etc, etc...]

Comment: what's the `self.dataDict.count` output?

Comment: `self.dataDict.count` = 4 - The complete dictionary outputs as: "["Number": "test", "Social": "test1", "Email": "test2", "Username": "test3"]. I have conditions for my other two dictionary keys within the IF statement also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Dictionary` try to use `Array` that contains your all keys with sorted and use that array with `tableViewDataSource` methods.

```
var keysArray = [String]()

keysArray = Array(dataDict.keys).sorted(<)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.keysArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (keysArray[indexPath.row] == "Number") {
        let firstcell:MyFirstCell = self.scanConfirmTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("scanfirst", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyFirstCell
        return firstcell
    }

    else if (keysArray[indexPath.row] == "Social") { 
        let secondcell:MySecondCell = self.scanConfirmTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("scansecond", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MySecondCell
        return secondcell
    }
    else {
        let emptycell:ScanEmptyCell = self.scanConfirmTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("scanemptycell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ScanEmptyCell
        return emptycell
    }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding :)